# How to AcquireToken with PromptBehavior in the latest Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-automation

In the older versions of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory there is AcquireToken with PromptBehavior parameter

```
var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/tenantId");
var result = context.AcquireToken(clientId: clientIdValue, redirectUri: new Uri("http://localhost/Appcycle"), resource: "https://management.core.windows.net/", promptBehavior: PromptBehavior.Auto);
```

In Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory v3.10 there is only AcquireTokenAsync

```
var authParam = new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto,false);
var result = context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.core.windows.net/", clientid, new Uri("http://localhost/AppPoolRecycle"), authParam);
result.Wait();
```

When I run this I get error
**{"Invalid owner window type. Expected types are IWin32Window or IntPtr (for window handle)."}**

Not sure if this is due to I am running on a console application. If so how do i get it to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because you are passing in "false" for the second parameter in the PlatformParameters constructor.

In the latest version of ADAL (Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory v3.10), this second parameter is (from https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/blob/7c9091a0edecf401fea402275e4a64aca95e40fe/src/ADAL.PCL.Desktop/PlatformParameters.cs):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the owner of the browser dialog which pops up for receiving user credentials. It can be null.
    /// </summary>
    public object OwnerWindow { get; private set; }
```

You're passing in false, which is accepted at compile time given that it's an object, but not at runtime given that it's not a window.

To fix this simply do not pass in this parameter or pass it in as null. This will make your console application launch a window which prompts the user to log in.

If this is meant to be a console application that's supposed to run **without** any user interaction though, then you should either use the app-only flow via this other overload of AcquireTokenAsync:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Acquires security token from the authority.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="resource">Identifier of the target resource that is the recipient of the requested token.</param>
    /// <param name="clientCredential">The client credential to use for token acquisition.</param>
    /// <returns>It contains Access Token and the Access Token's expiration time. Refresh Token property will be null for this overload.</returns>        
    public async Task<AuthenticationResult> AcquireTokenAsync(string resource, ClientCredential clientCredential)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was planning to run without any user interaction. ClientCredential takes only ClientId and ClientSecret. From what I have read ClientSecret is only available only for web app not for "Native Client Application" which is what Console app is. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: You are correct, we are developing a native WPF application and need user interaction because we don't have a secret.