# Azure service principal creation through Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am able to register application by following information provided in [Creating Azure AD application and a service principal using .NET Core (the API and HTTP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863284/creating-azure-ad-application-and-a-service-principal-using-net-core-the-api-a/44868832#44868832), but when I tried the following endpoint using Postman, I got an Insufficient Privileges error.

As I am able to create an app with the API, I don't believe it is a permission issue.

```
POST https://graph.windows.net/{{tenant_id}}/servicePrincipals?api-version=1.6
```

body like this:

```
{
  "appId":"eb167a6d-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-46e981be37fa"
}
```

and getting this error

```
{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en",
            "value": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the details of how you obtained the access token you used to make the API request?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that there are two kinds of permissions. **Delegated permissions** and **Application permissions**. You can see the difference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-permissions-and-consent#types-of-permissions).

[image]

It depends on the way you used to get the access token. If you get the token without a signed-in user, you need to use application permissions and grant admin consent.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have granted Application and Delegated permissions i.e. Delegated (work or school account) Directory.AccessAsUser.All and Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy and Directory.Read.All, Application.ReadWrite.All and Directory.Read.All with Admin consent. In fact, i have assigned more permissions than this for testing. I am using "https://graph.windows.net" as a resource type for getting access token.

Comment: @James Can you share the details of how you obtained the access token?

Comment: Getting from this end point-  post to https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenentID/oauth2/token

Comment: @James What is the value of `grant_type`? And please provide the screenshot of your permission list in the portal.