# Authenticate UWP Client and .Net Core Web App with Customers' Active Directory (Azure or ADFS)

Tags: azure, authentication, uwp, active-directory, adfs

I am building a UWP app and .Net Core API. Both should be deployed at the customers' on-premises and authenticated with Azure Active Directory.
Is there a way to authenticate the users without registering the application manually (And specifying the client id and other variables)?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to authenticate the users without registering the application manually.

[Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-users) (Azure AD) is Microsoft’s multi-tenant, cloud based directory and identity management service. You have need to register the application, if you authenticated with Azure Active Directory.

For ADFS, you could refer to [**AD FS Scenarios for Developers**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/overview/ad-fs-scenarios-for-developers), and it also need to register app at first.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to register the application programmatically in C# and get the ClientID and other parameters needed? I want to register the client for each customer automatically without their interference.

Comment: Hi Nico, I was wondering if you have any answer for the above. In other words, can we create one app with all Azure Active Directory users without registering the app for each client?

Comment: Sorry for my delay, you could register the application programmatically in C#, And I have found some [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44619481/login-azurermaccount-and-related-equivalents-in-net-azure-sdk/44631758#44631758) that you could [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684821/how-to-add-application-to-azure-ad-programmatically).